# SQL - count of how many employees worked on each project

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i have a assignment and have made a `ERD`, `data dictionary`, and implemented it in `wampserver`

i need some help with the following ***query***:

```
A count of how many employees worked on each project
```

Here is my ERD Solution i have made already
http://postimg.org/image/nkkscem4d/

```
PROJECT (ProNo, Emp_No, Pro_Name, Pro_Leader, Pro_Total) 

EMPLOYEE (EmpNo, Job_Class, Emp_Fname, Emp_Lname) JOB (Job_Class, Job_Desc, Job_Charge_Hr) 

ASSIGN (ProNo, EmpNo, Assign_Hours, Total_Charge)
```

Comment: sorry i was trying to upload a image

Comment: Plz share your schema

Comment: PROJECT (ProNo, Emp_No, Pro_Name, Pro_Leader, Pro_Total)
EMPLOYEE (EmpNo, Job_Class, Emp_Fname, Emp_Lname)
JOB (Job_Class, Job_Desc, Job_Charge_Hr)
ASSIGN (ProNo, EmpNo, Assign_Hours, Total_Charge)

Comment: Here is the ERD         http://postimg.org/image/nkkscem4d/

Comment: this sounds like homework to be honest "your erd" not the teachers erd?

Comment: Is a emplyoee supposed to be counted if assigned to a project, but has no hours worked (yet)?

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` is an aggregate function, so you can use `GROUP BY` to separate its return value by a column.

```
SELECT Project, COUNT(*)
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Project
```

This assumes the project is stored in the same table as the employees. If they aren't then you'll need to use a `JOIN`, but the use of `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` will be the same.

Comment: Ok thanks, i am confused on how to use INNER JOINS   the table employee and project are separate have a look at my ERD

Comment: Your schema wasn't posted when I wrote this, so I'd go with Matt's answer, which takes your schema into account and does the JOINs for you.

Comment: Just replace table and column names and you're done!

Answer (score 1):

Use `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT p.Pro_Name, Count(e.EmpNo)
FROM Project p
INNER JOIN Assign a ON p.ProNo = a.ProNo
INNER JOIN Employee e ON a.EmpNo = e.EmpNo
GROUP BY p.Pro_Name
```

Comment: i received the following

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'p.PROJECT' in 'field list'

Comment: Fixed, use Pro_Name instead of project

Comment: ok thanks matt let me check

Comment: god damn matt worked great